# Audio is not getting play in UIWebView using objective C

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

I am working in a project in which I am using **UIWebView**. The Project is in **Objective C**. I tried to load HTML string in a webView which contains Audio. But some how Audio is not getting play in iPhone. But it's playing in iPad. I tried to find the problem which I am getting. But unfortunately I couldn't found any solution for this. Please help me in this.

[image: I am sharing the screen shot of the problem]

Answer (score 0):

UIWebView is deprecated and not supported by apple anymore.
I might consider using the new framework - WKWebView.
You can import it by using

```
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>
```